# Find out if a file contains a given file signature

Tags: c, file

I want to traverse a given directory and find if a given file signature is present in any regular files of that directory.

Here's my code:

```
char* given_signature = "981d0000ec33fffffb06000000460e10";

int file_sign(char* path){

    FILE* file = fopen(path, "rb");

    if(!file){
        printf("error with file opening");
        return -1;
    }

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    long filelen = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    char* buffer = malloc(filelen);

    if(buffer)
        fread(buffer, 1, filelen, file);
    
    fclose(file);

    for(int i = 0; i < filelen - 16; i++){
        if(memcmp(buffer + i, given_signature, 16) == 0){
            printf("Signature found in %s\n", path);
        }
    }

    free(buffer);

    return 0;

}

void traverse_dirs(char* base_path){

    char path[_MAX_LINE_];
    struct dirent* dp;
    DIR* dir = opendir(base_path);

    if(!dir)
        return;

    while((dp = readdir(dir)) != NULL){
        if(strcmp(dp->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(dp->d_name, "..") == 0)
            continue;
        
        strcpy(path, base_path);
        strcat(path, "/");
        strcat(path, dp->d_name);

        if(dp->d_type == DT_REG){
            file_sign(path);
        }
        
        traverse_dirs(path);

    }

    closedir(dir);

}
```

The traversal is done correctly as it works for some other functions. So the problem is in the `file_sign()` function but I cannot find what I did wrong.

Could it be that I'm implementing the given signature wrong? e.g: can I do it like this:

```
char* given_signature[] = {"98", "1d", "00", "00", "ec", "33", "ff", "ff", "fb", "06", "00", "00", "00", "46", "0e", "10"};
```

and parse the file byte by byte? If yes how do I do that?

Any ideas?

Comment: Potential safety issue: If you were ever to make `filelen` an unsigned value (which would be a good choice), you would have a problem with the loop over `i < filelen - 16` in cases where the file is too short, because subtracting past zero will wrap to a huge number. Consider testing `i + 1 < filelen` or doing a size check before even attempting a search. Also, I think you might want to use `<=` here. Think about the simplest case where your file is actually 16 bytes long. You still need to loop once.

Comment: @paddy ... or `i < filelen - 16` --> `i + 16 < filelen`.

Comment: That's what I tried to write and somehow wrote 1 instead of 16, whoops!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're clearly confused between a string and binary data.

The string literal you showed is 33 bytes long (including null terminator) and consists of purely hex digits. These have nothing to do with the bytes that you're trying to represent.

Similarly, the array you showed is 16 pointers to 3-byte string literals. Also nothing to do with the binary data you're trying to find.

What you wanted is this:

```
char given_signature[] = {
    0x98, 0x1d, 0x00, 0x00,
    0xec, 0x33, 0xff, 0xff,
    0xfb, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x46, 0x0e, 0x10
};
```